# FindViewById in Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, findviewbyid

I'm working at a application in which I use fragments and a naviagaton drawer Activity.
I did there some basic things for which I oft often had to write "findViewById".

```
spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

Normally it works fine but in th onCreatView of a fragment I got troubles. Everywhere the programm says "cannot resolve method findviewbyid" where I use findviewbyId.

I read many questions and answers to this subject and tried everything out:

1.

```
spinner = (Spinner)getView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
```

2.

```
spinner = (Spinner)getActivity.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
```

3.

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
spinner = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
return v;
```

But no of that helps to solve my problem...

Complete code:

```
public class First extends Fragment {

    Spinner spinner;


    public First() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    }
}
```

So how can I use textviews, imageviews, spinner and so on in a fragment ???

**EDIT:**
I made a new simple project and know I can work with Buttons, TextView..., but I dont know if it's normal to get in fragments warning while initializing Objects:

```
textView=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

When I go with my mouse on (TextView) I get this report:

```
Casting 'v.findViewById(R.id.textView)' to 'TextView' is redundant
```

Is this okay? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

this should solve the problem
modify `onCreateView()` as below:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
spinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
return view;
```

Note that layout `fragment_first` should have the Views you wish to find (i.e the spinner) in this case.

Comment: this didn't solve my problem. What do you mean with the last sentence? That I need a spinner and the spinner id in the first_fragment xml file ? Yes I have this

Comment: @user7940193 what i mean is, the Spinner object should be added to the XML layout file you are inflating, and it should have the id `spinner`, what error do you get now? `NullException` or compile error or what?

Comment: Yes I did it, but it didn't work. Now I created a new very simple project and it works, don't know what I did wrong, but I have an other error. I will add the code to the question soon

Comment: OK no I will write a new question because it doesn't belongs directly to this question

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Defines the xml file for the fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_foo, parent, false);
    spinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: This was not there in your complete code. Try the solution.